# Can we pass multiple values inside $sce.trustAsHtml

Tags: angularjs

Currently in our site there are many context which has links embedded in it. We're bringing those context from json files and embedding as html. For each and every context, we're using $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.localData.LANDING_PAGE.DESCRIPTION_WITH_LINK.SAMPLE_TEXT). We're trying to avoid too many lines like this. Is there a way to avoid/ optimize it?

```
$scope.Sample_Link = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.localData.LANDING_PAGE.DESCRIPTION_WITH_LINK.SAMPLE_TEXT1); 
            $scope.Sample_Link2 = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.localData.LANDING_PAGE.DESCRIPTION_WITH_LINK.SAMPLE_TEXT_2); 
            $scope.Sample_Link3 = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.localData.LANDING_PAGE.SAMPLE_TEXT_3); 
            $scope.Sample_Link4 = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.localData.LANDING_PAGE.SAMPLE_TEXT_4);
            $scope.Sample_Link5 = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.localData.LANDING_PAGE.MODAL_WINDOWS.SAMPLE_TEXT_5);  
            $scope.Sample_Link6 = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.localData.LANDING_PAGE.MODAL_WINDOWS.SAMPLE_TEXT_6);
            $scope.Sample_Link7 = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.localData.LANDING_PAGE.MODAL_WINDOWS.SAMPLE_TEXT_7);
            $scope.Sample_Link8 = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.localData.LANDING_PAGE.MODAL_WINDOWS.SAMPLE_TEXT_8);
            $scope.Sample_Link9 = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.localData.LANDING_PAGE.MODAL_WINDOWS._9);
            $scope.Sample_Link10 = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.localData.LANDING_PAGE.MODAL_WINDOWS.SAMPLE_TEXT_10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a filter and use it in views

```
app.filter('mysce', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });

<div ng-bind-html="value | mysce"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Narek Mamikonyan! It worked like a charm! I avoided almost 50 lines of code in my page.. :)